# Count How Many License Registered in the specific month

Tags: excel-formula

How to formula using CountIf function in Excel to get the count of licenses registered in January given the Register date is complete date format. Below is the sample structure of Excel data. As shown in the table below, there are 3 licenses registered in the month of January.

[image: License Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column for the month, which I'll call `B`, and put the following function in the first cell of that column, and then copy it down:

```
=Month(B1:B4)
```

Then where you want the count to appear (I used `C5`), use the following formula:

```
=CountIf(B1:B5, 1)
```

This displays the following results:

[image]

This correctly performs the count regardless of the date format for the cell, as long as it's a date. In other words, it works for `mm/dd/yyyy`, `d/m/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, and `yyyy/mm/dd` equally as well, which removes the issue of trying to parse out the first two characters of a string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but if there's a way to solved it without a helper column would be great!

Comment: I don't believe there is a way without a helper column. You can always hide the column or move it to the end of the sheet and make it outside the printable range.

Comment: I guess so, because been searching from different internet sources and no yield so I ended here in Stack Overflow. Moreover, your solution really is a BIG help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various methods but i had to unfortunately use helper column to extract month number from dates. I used left function to extract month number as Left(B2,2). Then i used countif function to count all cells have "01"  countif(C2:C6,"01"). This is not the best solution but it worked.
[image]

Comment: That only works if the cell is a string, or the cell is a date that has the specific format "mm/dd/yyyy".

Comment: Yup i know  but i did this because Eliseo said "Register date is complete date format" and i could see its in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. Moreover when i tried using month function its giving me error #Value! Can you please tell me the reason for it.  See Screenshot attached https://prnt.sc/13xbo19

Comment: But it breaks if the date format is changed. Parsing a date as a string is a poor solution when there is a much better one available (see my answer). Note I did not downvote your answer; I simply left a comment.

Comment: Thanks Ken White. I am not at all offended by your comment rather m humbly asking you that i tried and got error. Could you please help me out why did this error occured. This is the reason i mentioned in my comments that this not the best solution but it worked for me.

Comment: I don't know what error you got, so I can't explain why it happened. I can tell you that the solution in my answer works with the sample data I provided - I tested it in Excel, and posted a screenshot of the results. That screenshot shows the exact formula I used in the formula bar at the top of the image. It also works if I change the date format to `mm/dd/yyyy` to have two-digit months.

Comment: Ohk Thanks Ken White.